# aChartEngine - add values (array) to XYseries in single function call

Tags: arrays, achartengine

To draw a linechart with aChartEngine we have to do the following -

```
XYSeries series = new XYSeries(seriesTitle);
for (int i=0; i < 1000; i++){  //add some data to series
    series.add(xval[i], yval[i]);
}
mDataset.addSeries(series);
XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
```

That is create a new series, add data to it and then add series to a dataset. Then create a renderer etc.

My question is that instead of calling series.add(x,y) in a for-loop multiple times, is it possible to add the whole array to the series at one go.

Something like -   series.addArray(xval[], yval[], NoOfValues);

This would save a lot of time. For 1000 points it will save 999 function calls.

Thanks

Comment: OMG ... There are not only 999 extra function calls (for every 1000 points), each of these calls are (in Source File - xyseries.java
function add() )
a) calling mXY.get(x) to search for duplicate entries in the series.
b) updating the range of x & y values.
c) adding data to the list.
Updating the range doesn't seem to be very expensive but searching for duplicates in thousands of entries is a different matter.
I tried  -    series.mXY.put(x,y)      but failed because mXY is private and not visible to my code.
Continued .....        in the next comment

Comment: Maybe a new function in xyseries.java can speed things up a bit ( I am new to Java/Android/Eclipse world & don't know what synchronized means but copying it here)

public synchronized void addArrayFast(double[] xVal, double[] yVal, NoOfPoints){
 for(int i=0; i<NoOfPoints; i++){
  mXY.put(xVal[i], yVal[i]);
  updateRange(xVal[i], yVal[i]);
 }
}

Any Comments please and directions to add this to aChartEngine source & build a new jar.

Thank you.